# How to form JSONObject in Android

Tags: android, json

I need help with form json object like this..

```
"Members":[{
                   "Id":"98",
                   "ActionId":"1",
                   "Notify":"Y"
               },
               {
                   "Id":"104",
                   "ActionId":"2",
                   "Notify":"N"
               },
               {
                   "Id":"108",
                   "ActionId":"3",
                   "Notify":"Y"
               }
           ]
```

i want to form Members object dynamically,How will i form this kind of JSON Object in android .please help me..
Thanks Friends,

Answer (score 4):

Refer these example to achieve your target,

[Examples](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_object)

Comment: @sure sahani,please post referal link for

Comment: Sorry can't get you, what referal you want.